# ESP8266 Button Latch - Always On

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, pcb, esp8266, lipo

I'm trying to build the following:

Press the button shortly, the ESP8285 should turn on.
GPIO16 can then be used to turn off the circuit.

The button press should **latch the power on.**

## The problem:

When I connect the 3.7 LiPo, the circuit is automatically on, without the button press.

I also cut the trace from GPIO16, circuit is always on.

What's wrong here?

[image: Circuit]

[image]

Comment: Is pin 1 of Q2 shorted to pin 3 of U3 by that gray via?

Comment: I should have explained. The 2 grey circles at the bottom right aren’t vias. They are VIN and GND terminals to solder on the battery wires. The board has no vias.

Comment: I know the large grey circles are your battery terminals, I meant the small grey circles. There is one next to the 'G' label of Q1 and one just to the left of 'C3'. What are those?

Comment: Oh those. They are just the marking of pin 1. No electrical connection.

Comment: I would measure (with power off) the resistance between the gate of Q1 and ground.  Because of your 100k R4 it had better be open or quite high to prevent pulling the gate of Q1 low enough to set off your latch. (also I am still confused why your small grey circles are grey if they are supposed to be a pin 1 indicator, which normally would be on the silk layer (yellow).)

Comment: Yeah, you're right, they should be on the silk layer. But I etched the board, so those grey circles are nothing.

The situation is exactly the same as before. The circuit is still "auto-on" !